# одинаковый message.chat.id

Tags: python, telegram-bot

такой вопрос уже был задан но там запускалось сразу два кода и поэтому id был одинаковым
у меня просто одинаковое id

```
import telebot
from datetime import datetime
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

print(bot.get_me())

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item4 = types.KeyboardButton('ассортимент')
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('информация')
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton('тех поддержка')
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('корзина')
        markup.add(item4, item2, item3, item1)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'привет',reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
        malob =  {message.chat.id : 1}
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
                if message.text == 'корзина':
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'чтобы вы хотели купить?')
                        print('BUY'+str(message.chat.id))

                elif message.text == 'информация':
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'бот создан для покупок жми что хочешь купить и жди ответа')
                        back =  types.KeyboardButton('назад')
                        markup.add(back)


                elif message.text == 'тех поддержка':
                        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'опишите пожалуйста свою проблему,а наш менеджер вскоре вам ответит')
                        print('HELP' + str(message.chat.id))
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'номер вашей жалобы-' + str(message.chat.id))
                        a_log = open(f'help_{message.chat.id}.txt', 'a')
                        a_log.write(f'{datetime.now()}: {message.text}\n')
                        back =  types.KeyboardButton('назад')
                        markup.add(back)




                elif message.text == 'ассортимент':
                        
                        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                        item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('мыло', callback_data='malo')
                        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('черепа', callback_data='cherep')
                        markup.add(item,item1)
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'вот наш каталог', reply_markup=markup)
                        
                        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
                        def callback(call):
                                if call.message:
                                        if call.data == 'malo':
                                                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                                                item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('+', callback_data='m+')
                                                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('-', callback_data='m-')
                                                markup.add(item,item1)
                                                malob[message.chat.id] += 1
                                                print(malob[message.chat.id])
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'вот наш каталог', reply_markup=markup)
                                                buy = open(f'fff_{message.chat.id}.txt', 'a')
                                                buy.write(f'мыло\n')
                                                
                                                


bot.polling()
```

он начинает быть одинаковым с строчки
def callback(call):

по моим предположениям это происходит из за того что наслаиваю одно на другое если да можете обьяснить как
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call): и тд
обьявить с самого начала